# Is it still possible to utilize a GPU on GCP on a individual account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have already activated billing but every time I tried to expand the quota it tells me:

'Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the request or until your Billing account has additional history'

I used to be able to get a GPU, but I can't seem to get one right now.

Comment: As the message informed you, you will need to wait. You might try opening a billing support ticket and explain your use case. Stack Overflow cannot help you with a vendor's policies. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite clear. The GPU quota increase will be gradually allowed as your Billing account will accumulate additional history

If you want to speed up the process, you might want to get in touch with the
[Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact)

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned. There is really not much that you can do except for two things:

1. Reply back to that email so your case gets reopened and you get to talk with a real person and not a bot.
2. If the real person still tells you that it's not possible to grant you the quota, then consider requesting a lower quantity, if you're already requesting only 1 GPU, then yes, go to the [Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) and explain your need, they may be able to vouch for you.